# Find Path in File

Tags: bash, macos, file, terminal, path

I got the temp file with a few lines of files

```
...
14G    /Users/admin/Desktop/xy
1G     /Users/admin/Desktop/yz
3G     /Users/admin/Desktop/za
18G    /Users/admin/Desktop
...
```

I only want to get one line with the "/Users/admin/Desktop" as output, but don't know how to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a minimal `awk` statement for this like,

```
awk '$2=="/Users/admin/Desktop"{print $1}' file
18G
```

(or) the entire line as

```
awk '$2=="/Users/admin/Desktop"' file
18G    /Users/admin/Desktop
```

Comment: It is important to check for the "Users/admin/Desktop", because that number in front of the line can change the value

Comment: @YannSerarcangeli: You want the entire line or just `18G` Refer my update.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `grep`:

```
grep "/Users/admin/Desktop$" file
```

The `$` will anchor the regular expression to the end of the line so you don't pick up the lines that contain subdirectories